# Missing "toInt()" from string after upgrading Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, spring-boot-starter-parent

Any suggestion on how to troubleshoot this?

[image]

Comment: try `.single().digitToInt()`

Comment: I thoght yoou should be able to use toInt()? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html

Comment: yeah I know incase you missed the file I thought it would be possible solution and can you show up the library you declared in gradle ?

Comment: Make sure Kotlin plugin is up to date in the IDE settings. Refresh the Gradle build and check for errors. Rebuild the project.

Comment: There are some [changes to the character conversions](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/char-int-conversions.md) in [Kotlin 1.5](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew15.html#stable-char-to-integer-conversion-api); in particular, `Char.toInt()` is deprecated.  However, `String.toInt()` is still around (as you can verify in the REPL).

Comment: Seeing latest Kotlin documentation on `String` the only available method is `toIntOrNull` https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/

Comment: Yes, but this is not showing as an alternative either :/

Comment: @BorisStrandjev `String.toInt()` still exists, it's in `kotlin.text`: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html

Comment: I agree with @Joffrey. @Stianhn, have you tried compiling `"1".toInt()`, even if your IDE highlighting indicates that it will not work?

Answer (score 3):

This could be an IntelliJ issue. Does the program compile with Gradle?

Assuming the former, try re-installing and/or updating the Kotlin plugin for IntelliJ. Also, try clearing caches via `File > Invalidate Caches ... > Invalidate and Restart`

Answer (score -3):

If you are planning on changing that digit or using it more than once, I would recommend making it a val or var. And the .toInt is available.

```
fun main() {
var number = "1"
val printThis = number.toInt()
println(printThis)
```

}

Comment: The OP is using a simple example just to illustrate that the function is missing.